# OneNote 2010 keeps crashing on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

It crashes a few second after lunching, reboot, and crash again endlessly until I kill the process.

I couldn't find the cache file, which some Google results suggested deleting.

Moreover - reinstalling did not help, nor did the downgrade to OneNote 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now on OneNote 2013. Deleting the cache worked for me. Here's how I did it on Windows 7.

1. Click the Windows / Start button and type `onenote /safeboot` into the run box (if you have a `Run` button instead of a text box, click that first)

[image]

2. Click `Delete Notebook Cache`.

[image]

OneNote should now open (and be stable). If not, try repeating this selecting `Delete Settings`.